# Map nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, lambda, nested

I would like to apply a map operation to three lists to compare their elements. Assuming I have

```
l1= [1,5]
l2=[1,3,5,7]
l3=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I would like a dictionary that would compare each element of l3 with l2 and carry on with l2 with l1

```
dictt= [{"1":{"1":[1,2],{"3":[3,4]}},{"5":[5,6],"5":[[6,7]]}]
```

I have achieved that with a long for loop but would rather to apply the 
map(func,arr) option.
Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What is your desired result after comparing all elements of two lists?

Comment: Compare l3 with l2 first ( the element must be less or e equal) . Carry the results with the comparison l2 to l1.

Comment: Can you show us the long for loop? The `dictt` isn't even syntactically correct, so one can only guess what the result should be...